# Did I just install a bad version of VLC

Tags: vlc

I'm new to Ubuntu and went to the app store to install VLC. I installed the first result I saw before I realized that they were actually quite different, with the one I installed seeming very off.

This is the one lower down that I should have installed:

[image]

This is the weird one that I uninstalled but is worrying me, with a conspicuously larger file size and no reviews:

[image]

I'm wondering if I should worry/reinstall my system/etc.

EDIT: Here's the output of `apt search vlc | grep inst`:

```
libbluray1/xenial,now 1:0.9.2-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  DVD-Video playing library - installer
libvcdinfo0/xenial,now 0.7.24+dfsg-0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvlc5/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvlccore8/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vlc/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
vlc-data/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 all [installed,automatic]
vlc-nox/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vlc-plugin-notify/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vlc-plugin-samba/xenial-updates,now 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

And this is the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' vlc\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs apt-cache policy` as suggested by David in the comments:

```
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.2-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
vlc-data:
  Installed: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.2-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
vlc-nox:
  Installed: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.2-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
vlc-plugin-notify:
  Installed: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
```

Comment: It could be that VLC had to install several dependencies. Did it work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question with the output of `apt search vlc | grep inst`.

Comment: You should definitely NOT reinstall your system.

Comment: @RayAntebioni it only worked when i installed the smaller file lower down. the first file didn't appear to do anything. i feel like if it were just a dependency issue it wouldn't be a separate, 120mb file

Comment: @snapcrack Well.. I would definitely NOT worry about it and just carry on if you fixed it.

Comment: @snapcrack provide the required output, please. Thank you.

Comment: i'm confused, do i just add `apt search vlc | grep inst` at the end of the post or is it supposed to go somewhere specific

Comment: Type `apt search vlc | grep inst` into a terminal and append the output to the end of the question.

Comment: it won't let me post more than two pictures and the output is really long

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be very interested in the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' vlc\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs apt-cache policy`. It's more surgical than the other suggested commands and only shows relevant info about VLC packages that you have actually installed.

Comment: added. my apologies, ctrl+C wasn't letting me copy and I didn't realize you could actually right-click and copy in the terminal in ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VLC is available in two package formats: both as a Debian package and as a snap. The "weird" one is probably the snap variant.

It's not a problem. The two package variants may co-exist. Or you may want to uninstall one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong with your system. You just installed and uninstalled a package, a tale as old as time. If you're worried about installing the "right" version of VLC, then in this case you could just

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

from a terminal in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No! Do not reinstall your system. If the one you got works than use it. If the other one worries you, and you removed it, there is nothing to worry about. This is not windows. Do not reinstall your whole system.

It may be a "bad" version, but if you uninstalled it, then do not worry.

Comment: This does not answer the question whether that one is a "bad" version of VLC or not.

Comment: This version is better. :) But please keep in mind that "may" is not very good in an answer. If OP asks if it's bad and you answer "may be" basically you are not answering. In this particular case a better answer would be "no, it's not a bad or malicious software if you found it in the standard Ubuntu repositories"... or something like that. ;)

Comment: I will keep note of such.

Comment: Why would you want to reinstall Windows?

Comment: It's not clear what "bad" means in this context, but the folks over at security.stackexchange will tell you that if you have installed compromised software on your machine then the **only** secure way out is reinstalling the OS from scratch. And some of the most concerned/paranoid users will claim that it is not enough and suggest you to throw away your pc and buy a new one.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This answer seems to suggest that reinstalling an Ubuntu system is unnecessary, unlike a Windows system, and I wanted to know the rationale behind such a statement.